# Android studio - ambiguous method call in inheritance chain (Kotlin Java interoperability)

Tags: java, android, android-studio, kotlin

So I have 3 classes - base Java -> Kotlin descendant -> Java descendant.

```
public class JavaParentClass {
    public <T> void doSmth(List<T> item) {}
}

open class KotlinDescendant : JavaParentClass() {
    override fun <T : Any?> doSmth(item: MutableList<T>?) {
        super.doSmth(item)
    }
}

public class JavaDescendant extends KotlinDescendant {
    void someMethod() {
        doSmth(new ArrayList<String>());
    }
}
```

For `JavaDescendant` class compiler in Android Studio shows error "Ambiguous method call. Both in KotlinDescendant and JavaParentClass match".

So as I understand lint just don't understand that `doSmth` is actually overriden in `KotlinDescendant` class.

Despite it works fine in runtime, what can be done to avoid this error?

Comment: Which line does the error appear?

Comment: So, I try your code in IDEA 2019.2 in Java project, and threre are no errors in this ide. What version on Android Studio you use?

Comment: The latest, 3.5.2. Thanks for info, so hope it will appear soon in Android Studio!

Answer (score 0):

android studio complains when you write java code inside Kotlin file or vice-versa, if you separate the 3 classes each in a its own file, calling them whether from java code or Kotlin code won't produce any error.